# Detect windows phone text messages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I'm making a game and it would be nice for it to know when the phone receives a text so the game can be paused. Is their any listener I can use? I've looked all over and it seems there isn't a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if the user receives a new text message, the toast notification will be shown at the top of the screen, but it shouldn't affect your game.

If the user taps the toast notification, then your game will be put into the background. The same process occurs if the user presses the home button or the search button.

So instead of worrying specifically about text messages, worry about how your game will handle being put into the background/suspended. If you get this right, you should have all scenarios where toast notifications arrive covered.

Comment: Yes but I would like to make the game automatically pause when the notification comes, it makes it easier for me to let it go background.

Comment: I agree with Alastair.  I would not want a game to pause because I received a spam text message.